Ubuntu 22.04 Bluetooth Settings -> No Bluetooth Found : despite Bluetooth toogle is available under the power button on the upper right
I have an intel nuc 7i5BNH. Bluetooth is working on the system level and bluetoothctl works. Bluetooth.service is up. I've looked at a lot of postings about drivers, etc, however the bluetooth system on the machine is working, it is just the gui front-end of ubuntu not seeing bluetooth.
systemctl status bluetooth.service outputs
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-05-14 09:49:29 UTC; 29min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 70937 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38236)
     Memory: 924.0K
        CPU: 4.610s
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─70937 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

May 14 09:49:29 vanaheim systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
May 14 09:49:29 vanaheim bluetoothd[70937]: Bluetooth daemon 5.64
May 14 09:49:29 vanaheim bluetoothd[70937]: Starting SDP server
May 14 09:49:29 vanaheim systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
May 14 09:49:29 vanaheim bluetoothd[70937]: Bluetooth management interface 1.21 initialized
May 14 09:49:29 vanaheim bluetoothd[70937]: src/adv_monitor.c:btd_adv_monitor_power_down() Unexpected NULL btd_adv
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue outputs
3a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:24fd] (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 [8086:9010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted

sudo dmesg|grep -i bluetooth outputs
[    5.729140] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.729163] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    5.729165] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.729169] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.729171] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.729174] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.879098] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.1 build 19 week 44 2021
[   12.632216] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   12.632219] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   12.632222] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   17.208692] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   17.208701] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   17.208705] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[43267.998995] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000d532a1d1 failed to resubmit (2)
[43291.057320] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.1 build 19 week 44 2021

rfkill list all outputs
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

I can scan for bluetooth devices, connect to them on the command line, but the ubuntu ui front-end keeps saying bluetooth not found.
blueman-manager sees bluetooth, it is just ubuntu settings does not
any help would be appreciated.

I've realized that the problem is within the gnome applet and have created a new question for that link
